# this.content is not updating with values from template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have the following template

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="friends/new">
    <label>First Name</label>
    {{input value=firstName}}<br />

    <label>Last Name</label>
    {{input value=lastName}}<br />

    <label>About</label>

    {{textarea value=about}}<br />
    <button {{action "create"}} {{bind-attr disabled=isInvalid}}>Create</button>
  </script>
```

I put data into all the fields and click the create button, which goes to the following controllers

```
App.FriendsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return { firstName: "", lastName: "", about: ""}
    }
});
App.FriendsNewController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: "friends",
    isInvalid: true,

    validForm: function(){

        if(this.get('lastName') && this.get('firstName')){
            this.set("isInvalid", false);
        } else {
            this.set("isInvalid", true);
        }

    }.observes('firstName','lastName'),

    actions: {
        create: function(){

            var newFriend = Ember.copy(this.content);

            console.log(newFriend);
        }
    }
});
```

When calling `this.get('lastName')` ect the content that I have entered into the text boxes is correct. But when I log `this.content`, the value is still the initial value that I set in the `FriendsNewRoute`. What do I need to do so that `this.content` correctly update with the current data in my template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change:

```
Ember.Controller
```

to

```
Ember.ObjectController
```